# Reactive form angular using FormArrayName

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In my form I need to add phones, I have seen that in the database you are saving a string array with the phone numbers that I added, but the moment the value returned from the database is set to the form, only the first array value is shown .

I would like to display all array values that contain number of phones in string format.

**component.html:**

```
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="start">
                            <div formArrayName="phones" fxFlex="30">
                                <div *ngFor="let phone of phones.controls; index as i">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <input matInput [formControlName]="i" placeholder="Phone Number">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex="30">
                                <button mat-raised-button class="blue" (click)="addPhone()">Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**component.ts:**

```
    this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        phones: new FormArray([new FormControl('')]),
    });

    this.values$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
        .subscribe((values) => {
            // values = {phones: ['999999', '88888', '77777']}
            if (values) {
                this.myForm.patchValue(values, { emitEvent: false });
            }
        });

     get phones(): FormArray { return this.myForm.get('phones') as FormArray; }
     addPhone(): void { this.phones.push(new FormControl('')); }
```

Even returning more than one value inside the array only displays the first array value on my form, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe there is just typo in the subscribe, where param is called `vales`, but you are using `values` inside the subscribe. https://stackblitz.com demo would speed up the problem hunting.

Comment: I posted the code here with typo but in my code it is correct ... it is displaying on the screen only the first string of the three that it contains in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`patchValue` won't create any form controls for you, so when you call patchValue it only sets the value for the first form control in your form array, because you only created one.

You have to call `addPhone` for each phone number or create form inside the describe when you already know how many form controls there should be, but you still need to create as many form controls as number of elements in your array.

```
this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    phones: new FormArray(),
});

this.values$
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
    .subscribe((values) => {
        if (values && values.phones) {
            phones.forEach(phone => this.addPhone(phone));
        }
    });

 get phones(): FormArray { return this.myForm.get('phones') as FormArray; }
 addPhone(phone = ''): void { this.phones.push(new FormControl(phone)); }
```